# store paragraph into mysql with php is adding extra characters

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

so this is what I input:

```
Hey this is a test
this is another line
```

and this is what I get inside mysql(when I check with phpmyadmin):

```
Hey%20this%20is%20a%20test%0Athis%20is%20another%20line
```

this is the query :

```
$storeme = nl2br(htmlentities($valeur, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

$quer = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE engine4_users SET billboard='$storeme' WHERE user_id='$userid' ");
```

so obviously each space is returned with a %20 and it doesn't save the line break.
how can I resolve that please? im using a `<textarea></textarea>` to receive the paragraph

Comment: you should store the text as it is in the database. When you want to fetch it and display it on the screen, then you use nl2br and htmlentities. Btw htmlentities is causing this character escape

Comment: don't use `htmlentities`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't treat the data before inputting it into mysql:

```
$quer = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE engine4_users SET billboard='".mysql_real_escape_string($storeme,$con)."' WHERE user_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($userid,$con)."' ");
```

Treat the data after when you fetch it.